# Slack: How to set custom shortcodes for emojis (short_name shortcodes)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, slack, emoji, hipchat

How do I set custom shortcodes for emojis that ship with Slack?

First, shortcodes (defined as `short_name` in the [source repo](https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data)) are what a user types that translates into an emoji. For example, the shortcode `:+1:` translates into a "thumbs-up" emoji.

From ICQ to Pidgin to HipChat to Slack, I have some hard-coded emoji shortcodes programmed into my head. For example, I find myself often typing `(y)` in slack, expecting it to turn into a "thumbs-up" emoji.

My best guess is that my coworkers have no idea what I'm saying, and I want slack to enter a "thumbs-up" emoji when I type `(y)`.

How can I change the shortcodes (or add additional shortcode aliases) for emojis in slack?